# iPhone contact sync no longer working with google

Tags: iphone, contacts, google-sync

Yesterday without warning, I lost all my google contacts on my phone, which is to say all my contacts. It had been working and syncing just fine, but now, nothing. I deleted the account under settings, revoked the application specific password on the google side, and started fresh. I followed the [directions at google](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/2753077?hl=en) to the letter and still nothing. Am I missing something? Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Ugh, of course while typing this, I do the one thing I hadn't tried.

I turned the phone off and then back on again.

It picked the sync up and now I'm back in business.